# Cannot create inner bean 'org.hibernate.event.spi.MergeEventListener#6ad5445a' of type [org.hibernate.event.spi.MergeEventListener]

Tags: spring, hibernate, wildfly

i am usind wildfly 10.1.0 when i run my dynamic web project i got following error

follownig is my application-context.xml file

```
<property name="eventListeners">
        <map>
            <entry key="merge">
                <bean
                    class="org.hibernate.event.spi.MergeEventListener" />
            </entry>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

so what class is required to set property eventlisteners

help with this problem
thank you

```html
15:49:47,994 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 499) Context initialization failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'inventoryChecksDAOTarget' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/revman-content.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'hsdSessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hsdSessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/application-context.xml]: Cannot create inner bean 'org.hibernate.event.spi.MergeEventListener#6ad5445a' of type [org.hibernate.event.spi.MergeEventListener] while setting bean property 'eventListeners' with key [TypedStringValue: value [merge], target type [null]]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.hibernate.event.spi.MergeEventListener#6ad5445a' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/application-context.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.hibernate.event.spi.MergeEventListener]: Specified class is an interface
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1492)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1237)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:552)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:759)
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866)
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
 at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:444)
 at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:326)
 at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
 at io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:187)
 at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:200)
 at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:171)
 at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
 at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
 at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
 at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
 at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
 at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
 at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
 at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:234)
 at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:100)
 at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:82)
 at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
 at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hsdSessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/application-context.xml]: Cannot create inner bean 'org.hibernate.event.spi.MergeEventListener#6ad5445a' of type [org.hibernate.event.spi.MergeEventListener] while setting bean property 'eventListeners' with key [TypedStringValue: value [merge], target type [null]]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.hibernate.event.spi.MergeEventListener#6ad5445a' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/application-context.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.hibernate.event.spi.MergeEventListener]: Specified class is an interface
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:313)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:122)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedMap(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:407)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:165)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1492)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1237)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:552)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
 ... 34 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.hibernate.event.spi.MergeEventListener#6ad5445a' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/application-context.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.hibernate.event.spi.MergeEventListener]: Specified class is an interface
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1116)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1060)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:299)
 ... 46 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.hibernate.event.spi.MergeEventListener]: Specified class is an interface
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:68)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1108)
 ... 50 more
```